# When using pyTrends: At which position within the code do I have to enter my "google password" and "google username" to login to google?

Tags: python

I use the following code to access google Trends:

```
from pytrends.request import TrendReq

# Login to Google. Only need to run this once, the rest of requests will use the same session.
pytrend = TrendReq()

# Create payload and capture API tokens. Only needed for interest_over_time(), interest_by_region() & related_queries()
pytrend.build_payload(kw_list=['pizza', 'bagel'])

# Interest Over Time
interest_over_time_df = pytrend.interest_over_time()
print(interest_over_time_df.head())
```

But it gives me this error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-d8061e19d0c7> in <module>
      2 
      3 # Login to Google. Only need to run this once, the rest of requests will use the same session.
----> 4 pytrend = TrendReq()
      5 
      6 # Create payload and capture API tokens. Only needed for interest_over_time(), interest_by_region() & related_queries()

TypeError: __init__() missing 2 required positional arguments: 'google_username' and 'google_password'
```

Where do I have to enter my google username and password?
is it within the `TrendReq()` method?
Thank you for your help!

Comment: show code snippet so that we can help

Comment: Welcome to SO https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: It's possible with ```Selenium``` _web driver_, so you can use it for solving your problem.

Comment: can you post the full error message?

Comment: Dear Hoxha, thank you, I added the complede error message. Please try to help me. Thank you from Germany.

Comment: Dear all, I solved the problem:
When using "pip install pytrends" an older version of pytrends was installed (version 4.1.1). When I did it with "pip install pytrends == 4.7.2" the newest version of pytrends was installed and no google authentification credentials were asked anymore.